# SMTP exception while implementing email feature

Tags: smtp

I am getting following exception while implementing mail feature for my local machine please help me  with this

> The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first. 21sm1768418wfi.5

Comment: Which language are you using? It will help us suggest a possible fix for your exception.

Comment: I am  implementing it in asp.net...

Comment: Please post an SSCCE of your problem, not just the error message.  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly as the message describes.

What ever SMTP server you're trying to connect to, requires you to use SSL for that connection, in addition to supplying a username&password.

SMTP over SSL typically occurs on port 465, however you will need to verify this setting with your mail provider.

So you need to specify the correct port, and specify the UseSSL flag.

Using C# it might look like this:

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.emailserver.com");

 mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@yahoo.com");
 mail.To.Add("to_address@coolguy.com");
 mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
 mail.Body = "This is a test message";

 SmtpServer.Port = 465;
 SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
 SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true; //<--- this will do SSL for you.

 SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```